# Sending code to an ansi-term via isend-mode: How to modify default buffer chosen and how to automatically open ansi-terms?

Tags: ansi-term

I use `isend-mode` (see [here](https://github.com/ffevotte/isend-mode.el/blob/master/isend-mode.el))
to send (bash) code to an `ansi-term` as follows:

```
1) `M-x ansi-term` # open ansi-term
2) Open buffer with code I want to send to *ansi-term*
3) `M-x isend RET *ansi-term* RET` # => associates code buffer with `*ansi-term*`
```

Then you can step through code with `C-RET` and see the output in `ansi-term`.
There are two things that are tedious:

1. On `M-x isend RET`, the current buffer name is suggested as output where
   to send the code to, but I never do that. I would like to have `*ansi-term*`
   as default there. This should be rather easy given the definition of
   `isend-associate` (see the above link, line 262), but I'm not an Elisp
   programmer (is it simply `(setq isend--command-buffer *ansi-term*)`?)
2. Ideally, `M-x ansi-term` in Step 1) would not be necessary. It would be great
   if calling `M-x isend RET *ansi-term*` would automatically open a new
   `ansi-term` (unless there's already one open in which case it should go to that)
   and associate it with the code buffer.
3. Out of interest, is there any other method that can send code from a buffer
   (.sh file) to an ansi-term (or even 'real' terminal provided by the OS) so
   that you can step through the code one line at a time or send regions?
   I didn't find any other ones but `isend-mode`.

Comment: Step 3 should be `M-x isend-associate RET *ansi-term* RET` if I understand correctly?

Comment: `M-x isend` is an alias for that, so also works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command should do steps 1 and 3, run it in the buffer you open in step 2 (bind to a key, or rename to something shorter, as you like).

```el
(defun isend-with-ansi-term ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((term-buf (get-buffer "*ansi-term*")))
    (unless term-buf
      (display-buffer
       (save-window-excursion ; Work around term.el's use of `switch-to-buffer'.
         (save-current-buffer
           (setq term-buf (ansi-term (or explicit-shell-file-name
                                         (getenv "ESHELL")
                                         shell-file-name)))))))
    (isend-associate (buffer-name term-buf))))

(defun isend-dissociate-on-kill (buffer-name)
  (let ((buf (get-buffer buffer-name))
        (orig-buffer (current-buffer)))
    (with-current-buffer buf
      ;; Disable `isend-mode' once the associated buffer is killed.
      (add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook
                ;; Backquote and comma could be dropped if using
                ;; lexical-binding.
                `(lambda ()
                   (with-current-buffer ,orig-buffer
                     (isend-mode -1)))
                nil t))))
(advice-add 'isend-associate :after #'isend-dissociate-on-kill)
```

> Do you know how to bind `M-x isend-with-ansi-term` to `C-RET` so that on the first `C-RET` it executes the function but subsequent `C-RET` work in `isend-mode` and send the code to `ansi-term`?

Just `(define-key global-map [C-return] 'isend-with-ansi-term)`. When `isend-mode` is turned on it will override that binding because minor mode bindings take precedence over global bindings.  (PS `RET` is `C-m` so `C-RET` doesn't work, you need `[C-return]` or `(kbd "<C-return>")` in this case).

---

> is it simply `(setq isend--command-buffer *ansi-term*)`?

Generally, the `--` in the name is a signal from the author that this variable might be renamed or somehow change its meaning in the future, so you shouldn't touch it.  See [(elisp) Coding Conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Coding-Conventions.html).

Comment: Thanks, npostavs. On `M-x isend-with-ansi-term`, the current buffer containing the code disappears and you just see the ansi-term, so you can't execute the code without changing the buffer again. Is there a way to open the ansi-term in a buffer you'd get when doing `C-x 4 c`?

Comment: @MariusHofert I think `display-buffer`+`save-window-excursion` should do the trick, see edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works great! If you don't mind, I'd suggest to the author of `isend-mode` to incorporate this function.

Comment: Do you know how to bind `M-x isend-with-ansi-term` to `C-RET` so that on the first `C-RET` it executes the function but subsequent `C-RET` work in `isend-mode` and send the code to `ansi-term`? That would be great (I can also ask a new question here).

Comment: @MariusHofert Sure, see edit.

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly, it works if I freshly open the code buffer after killing it. But when I kill *ansi-term* and then do C-RET again from the code buffer, it doesn't: `funcall-interactively: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`

Comment: @MariusHofert Ah, arguably a bug in isend, but I edited in some `advice-add` which should fix it.