# isend: Why additional C-RET required when sending code to ansi-term?

Tags: key-bindings, ansi-term

The following code (from [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/50539/sending-code-to-an-ansi-term-via-isend-mode-how-to-modify-default-buffer-chosen)) allows to send lines of code to an open `*ansi-term*` buffer
via `C-RET`. It works well but the very first time I hit `C-RET`, the current
line is not sent (nothing happens). Only from then on does `C-RET` send
the current line to the `*ansi-term*` buffer. Why is the additional `C-RET`
required in the beginning?

```
(defun isend-with-ansi-term ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((term-buf (get-buffer "*ansi-term*")))
    (unless term-buf
      (display-buffer
       (save-window-excursion
         (save-current-buffer
           (setq term-buf (ansi-term (or explicit-shell-file-name
                     (getenv "ESHELL")
                     shell-file-name)))))))
    (isend-associate (buffer-name term-buf))))
(define-key global-map [C-return] 'isend-with-ansi-term)
```